# What should I use to make sure my CSS works with all browsers?

Tags: html, css

I've heard of preprocessors, post processors, LESS, SASS, SESSPOOL and others. What do I need to make my CSS work better across all browsers? Should I use multiple libraries?

Here is an example code:

```
<div id="myDiv">some content</div>
```

CSS:

```
#myDiv {
    border-radius: 8px;
}
```

Comment: And what would `work better` mean in this context?

Comment: [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) + [Bourbon](http://bourbon.io/).

Comment: Pre/Post processors are not directly related to browser compatibility. Your specific problem can be solved using additional vendor specific directives.

Comment: I think you are looking for "vender-prefixes" when using "newer" css-rules

Comment: @haim770 so none of the libraries I listed add vendor prefixes? i don't want to have to keep 100's of prefixes up in my head just to make corners work in older browsers.

Comment: [autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) is your friend.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts, The libraries themselves don't add vendor prefixes but almost any of them provide plugins that do (and you'll have to manually use them in code). Post processors will (usually) do that automatically for you though.

Comment: @DanPrince - Bourbon looks pretty good. That's mostly what I'm looking for. Unfortunately, some assholes put this question on hold.

Comment: @steveax Autoprefixer is exactly what I'm looking for. Maybe write that as an answer. Here's a quote from their page: Just write normal CSS according to the latest W3C specs and Autoprefixer will produce the code for old browsers. 

a {
    display: flex;
}

compiles to:

a {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex
}

Autoprefixer has 27 special hacks to fix web browser differences.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts: reason he didn't write that as an answer is because it's not remotely as simple as prefixing all the things and bam. Cross-browser CSS.

Comment: @BoltClock so let's say I use that autoprefixer. you're saying I'm going to still have problems. what sort of problems will I encounter? what should I do?

Comment: @1.21 gigawatts: That's why your question is too broad. It's difficult to answer exhaustively what sort of problems you will encounter because CSS itself covers a wide range of features.

Comment: Well instead of closing it maybe you could have asked me to be more specific??? I don't think it's too broad either. I want to make my CSS work in more browsers. What everyone is saying RIGHT NOW is what I need to hear. If I wrote it any other way I don't think I'd get the information I need.

Comment: yep, check out this cool snippet you ca use as well https://gist.github.com/jshawl/6225945

Comment: ok. i looked at that and i think i understand what it does. saving it for later...

Comment: @BoltClock the reason you say it's too broad is because there is a lot involved. that's true. what i think i need is to see someone going through the process. maybe a twitch video or something. i don't know gulp, grunt, sass, less, autoprefixer, command line, etc. i don't know any of that stuff. only what it says on their web sites or githubs. i've read them numerous times in fact. i think the command line thing is messed up. for me I've had code editors, IDE's & even notepad. I save that & now it's viewable in the browser! now u have this CLI that is supposed to do everything??? wait what?

Comment: ...and yes I'm f*#$*ng mad because everyone talks about it like it's common knowledge and people mark questions "too broad" (this has happened before) and no one is explaining this side of it.

Comment: Your question is both too broad and soliciting opinions (which one should I use?).You're supposed to do research *before* asking questions.  Did you look into any of the CSS preprocessors?  Try installing one?  Try writing some code for one?  Asking a question on SO should be literally the *last* place you go when you're trying to solve a problem (which you don't even have).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Concerning Preprocessors:**

When it comes to preprocessors **ALL** of them are compiled back down to regular old CSS.

**Prefixing:**

Prefixing comes into play when you're using some of the latest CSS3 properties, if you're not sure if it's supported always check.

**What is supported what prefixes do I need?**

Here are some links that will tell you what prefixes you will need for the latest CSS3 properties.

[What CSS should I Prefix?](http://shouldiprefix.com/)

A comprehensive list of CSS3 browser support: [CSS3 Browser Support Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_browsersupport.asp)

**I'm lazy prefix me!**

You can use http://pleeease.io/play/ in your browser to prefix for you, works best on small projects.

For bigger projects its more practical to use tools such as [Autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) with task runners like Gulp & Grunt. That way you can prefix your CSS directly from your CLI!

Comment: That's kindof my question. Do any of these libraries add all the vendor prefixes for me? I thought that's what they did.

Comment: no, but there are some autoprefixers online that will prefix for you. It's a copy and paste method that is super easy. Use http://pleeease.io/play/ and I added that to my answer as well

Comment: I can't believe there isn't something that does this already. thanks for the links. if nothing else exists I might write it myself. EDIT: Our posts crossed. That link looks like what I want. I'm hoping I can drop my whole CSS file in it.

Comment: have you check out Autoprefixer? you can use it with Grunt and Gulp from NPM.

Comment: just read about that. looks like its what i'm looking for.

Comment: you'll love using it from the command line, super easy.

Comment: kewl. i'll check it out. so install gulp and grunt and then run autoprefixer on my css.

Comment: Yes, you can do all of that from the CLI `npm install --global postcss-cli autoprefixer
postcss --use autoprefixer *.css -d build/`

Comment: so that will run on all my css files as they change (are saved)?

Comment: Leaving it unedited because I want people to recognize that I don't know what I'm talking about. The edit makes it sound like I do.

Comment: Gist to run from CLI https://gist.github.com/jshawl/6225945

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these steps to make your css rule compatible to various browser.

1. check whether css rules that you are using is supported by various browser using this link  http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius
2. Add the prefixes using this link http://pleeease.io/play/

As you mentioned LESS,SASS preprocessors, There are meant for scripting the css which will help you write a re-usable code (i.e. mixins) and when you compile these less or sass script, you would get well formatted CSS file.

First two steps mentioned above should solve your issues. if you use this two steps while scripting using LESS or SASS then you will end up with well crafted CSS and will improve your productivity as well.

Comment: Mixins are a way of including ("mixing in") a bunch of properties from one rule-set into another rule-set. So say we have the following class:
.bordered {
  border-top: dotted 1px black;
  border-bottom: solid 2px black;
}
And we want to use these properties inside other rule-sets. Well, we just have to drop in the name of the class where we want the properties, like so:

#menu a {
  color: #111;
  .bordered;
}

.post a {
  color: red;
  .bordered;
}
The properties of the .bordered class will now appear in both #menu a and .post a. (Note that you can also use #ids as mixins.)

Comment: if you want more details on mixins refer http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature

Answer (score -1):

you need to use vendor prefixes.

```
Typically the vendors use these prefixes:

-webkit- (Chrome, newer versions of Opera.)
-moz- (Firefox)
-o- (Old versions of Opera)
-ms- (Internet Explorer)
Vendors also use prefixes on API. On interfaces, they typically use:

Webkit (Chrome, newer versions of Opera.)
Moz (Firefox)
O (Old versions of Opera)
MS (Internet Explorer)
On properties and methods, they typically use:

webkit (Chrome, newer versions of Opera.)
moz (Firefox)
o(Old versions of Opera)
ms (Internet Explorer)
```

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix

Comment: where is the defination of an answer ? according to merriam-webster:  something you say or write when someone asks you a question

: a response to a question that is meant to show whether or not you know something (such as a question asked as part of an exam)

: the correct response to a question

Comment: You have to add more explanation to your answer.

Comment: so its an answer ?I believe in  short phrases than long articles.

Comment: I don't like to give you downvote. Please, explain more rather that one sentence.

Comment: then please write you want to know more than just writing its a comment !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96455/discussion-between-hamslan-and-alireza-safian).